# Join close parallel lines to one line in CAD to GIS workflow

Tags: qgis, fme-form, geometry-conversion

I have a DWG that contains a very detailed drawing of an area. Especially every wall in that area is depicted as 3 close parallel lines.

For further processing in my GIS tools, i would like to combine these close parallel lines into one.

I thought about using FME tools, but the options are overwhelming.

What options do i have to achieve that workflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a lot of ways this could be achieved in FME. I think it depends on whether you want to simply keep the centre line, or try and merge the three lines somehow (since they're parallel I can't see a reason for that).

So, one method would be to buffer each line [Bufferer] (if you know they are 1m apart, then buffer them by 1.25m for example), dissolve the buffers together [Dissolver], and then replace each buffer with a new centre line [CentreLineReplacer]. This basically takes the whole wall and recreates it as a new line.

[image]

Another method might be to try and identify which is a centre line and which is a parallel one. Try a NeighborFinder in Candidates Only mode. Which ever line has two neighbors (or two with a distance greater than 1m for example) should be the centre.

Hope this helps. I've created a workspace for the Buffer/Dissolver method and you can find it in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xux6xzs164h8uvp/BufferDissolver.fmwt?dl=0).